# replace width of image while inserting into db

Tags: php, html, regex, string

I have a blog system where user inputs the image url in the post content like

```
hey how are you <img src="example.com/image.png" style="width: 952px;">
```

if the user has written like this

```
hello how are you <img src="example.com/image.png" style="width: 952px;">
```

Then I want to find this `style` `width` `952px` line and replace it into `100%`

the user can input any dimension of image like 100px 300px
here is what I have tried:

$content is what user have posted

```
  $go = $content;
  $mystr= $go;
  $start=strpos($mystr,'style="width: ');
  $end=strpos($mystr,'">');
  $jo = substr($mystr,0,$start+strlen('') ) . 'style="width: 100%;' . 
  substr($mystr,$end);
```

The problem i'm facing is that if user puts two or three image tag but this script is only replacing one width value how to replace multiple width

the user inputs->

```
  <img src="example.com/img.png" style="width: 500px;"><br><img 
  src="example.com/img2.png" style="width: 952px;">
```

here what i got as result

```
  <img src="example.com/img.png" style="width: 100%;"><br><img 
  src="example.com/img2.png" style="width: 952px;">
```

second image did'nt changed value of width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` function:

```
$go = preg_replace('/style="width:\s*\d+px;/i', 'style="width:100%;', $content);
```

That's assuming $content has only your `<img>` tags, otherwise you may mess up other html elements.

Comment: any other way not to mess up with other html tags? what if i use <img src=" " style="width:300px;"> what will preg_replace for it

Comment: It will work correctly, but if you have let's say `<span style="width:50px;">...</span>` it wil become `<span style="width:100%;">...</span>` too

Answer (score 0):

This case is perfect for regular expression search and replace.
In PHP you would use **preg_replace** , documentation for which you can find here:
 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace the width in each img tag, e.g.

```
echo preg_replace("/<img.*?\Kwidth:\s*[^;]*/s", "width:100%", $input);
```

Simply exanied we first match everything until  the width attribute in a img tag (`<img.*?`) and then reset the match with `\K` so we then can match the width attribute(`width:\s*[^;]*/`) and replace it with `width:100%`.

Comment: what if the image width is under 250 px so is there any way to only change width of image only when it is above 250 px?

Comment: @abhishekverma Yes, then just change out `[^;]*` with `(2[5-9]\d|[3-9]\d{2})px` at the end of the regex